# How to avoid re rendering of functional component when using data from store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Want to use some data from store and for which fetching it using selectors but the problem is it that I don't want to re render the component when data is changed

```
export function App() {
  const userStatus = useSelector(selectUserStatus);
  return userStatus === UserFetchStatus.LoadingFromStorage ||
    userStatus === UserFetchStatus.Loading ? (
    <Spinner /> 
  ): <Content />; }
```

Is there any way to get this data without making a re render cycle?

Comment: [Please don't ask the same question multiple times in a brief time period.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68411077/re-render-react-functional-component-only-when-certain-condition-is-met). You can edit your existing question to clarify it, if necessary, instead of opening a new one.

Comment: In one case I don't want to re render the component in just one specific condition and in other case i never want to re render the component when its value is changed

Comment: Also please write complete code because in this example you're missing the third part of the ternary statement

Comment: If you *never* want to rerender the component when a specific piece of data changes, just don't have it import that data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'; 
import { useStore } from 'react-redux';
import { includes } from 'fp';

const isLoading = includes([
  UserFetchStatus.LoadingFromStorage,
  UserFetchStatus.Loading]
);

const App = () => {
  const store = useStore();
  const { userStatus } = store.getState();
  return isLoading(userStatus) ? <Spinner /> : <Content />;
};
```

This should work because according to `react-redux` docs, the `useStore` doesn't update the component when the state changes https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#usestore